# Swift package link with system framework

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, swift-package-manager

Can somebody tell me please how to link a system Framework to a Target in the Swift Package manager?
When I link it directly in Xcode it works perfectly, but I don't know how to specify that in the Package.swift file.

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: System frameworks should be automatically linked in SwiftPM, which framework are you trying to link?

Comment: Im trying to link AppKit and DFRFoundation (private framework from apple). Unfortunately they are not linked by default

Comment: Any update? I am also trying to link with Webkit and CoreLocation. But still don't know how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't solve this problem